# ReactiveCocoa, Module compiled with Swift 2.3 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0 issue. How to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-cocoa

I have 2 Xcodes in my Mac(7.3.1 & 8.1). I want to work with ReactiveCocoa so I installed it via Cocoapods and later with Carthage. And when I import later in my ViewController `import ReactiveCocoa` I get the next error:

```
Module compiled with Swift 2.3 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0: /Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RAC-grddczfrbaumbtglfcuzhxyzoodk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactiveCocoa.framework/Modules/ReactiveCocoa.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule
```

How can I fix that? I'm already working over it over 3-4 hours and nothing

Comment: what's the version that u added to the pod? "pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 4.2'"?

Comment: @Ahmad yes, it is

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the latest [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) (github):

> "This documents the RAC 5 which targets Swift 3.0.x ..."

I assume that should not install 4.x version. try to  "pod 'ReactiveCocoa'" -for installing the latest version-, version 5 for targeting Swift 3.

Also, check the section "[Objective-C and Swift](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#objective-c-and-swift)".

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for ReactiveCocoa that supports Swift 3.0, ReactiveCocoa 5.0 alpha 1 and the `master` branch does not support CocoaPods yet. But the support is WIP.

In the meantime, you may try the [`rex-modulemap`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/pull/3252) branch.